# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Get Controller and Action and Perform Redirect from Application_OnAuthenticateRequest Method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have implemented the Application_OnAuthenticateRequest method in my Global.asax class in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application. When a user hits a page on my application, I load the user and verify their account status. When their account status does not match the valid account statuses, I want to redirect that user to a controller/action to perform additional actions.

The problem I am having is that I need to get the controller/action from the request to ensure that an infinite loop of redirects doesn't occur. I also am not sure of the best way to handle the redirect in this method to my new controller/action.

Any way to do this?

Comment: While there may be a way to do that, it might be easier to just go back and implement the MembershipProvider interface.  Then you can add a decorator to any function that you want to automatically make sure the user has the approriate level of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to put your logic inside a custom Authroze Filter instead of Application_OnAuthenticateRequest method. [Check this link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1573254/3948251.aspx)

Comment: This was the easiest to enforce across my entire site.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you could put [Authorize] before your method signature and this will redirect the user to another view if they are not authorized.

Answer (score 0):

How about a Custom Method to authorize the user and Try/Catch?
In "Catch" send him to the View you want.